# MSW, blob size in multipart/form-data in request becomes 0

Tags: javascript, mocking, playwright, form-data, msw

In one of my endpoints I need to add a multipart/form-data. the formData is created like so:

```
// inputData is just an object: { info: 'something' } created by a form.
// file is an image but irrelevant in this question
const blob = new Blob([inputData], { type: 'application/json' });
const formData = new FormData();

formData.append('data', blob);
formData.append('file', file);
```

When I intercept this endpoint using MSW and access the body in the request I can see the `file` and `data`. To access data I'm using the follow code:

```
const addInfo = rest.post(url, async (req, res, ctx) => {
  const { data } = req.body;
  const text = await data.text();

  const { info } = JSON.parse(text);
  return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json({ info }));
});
```

When running my Playwright tests, this works fine. `data` is found and `data.text()` returns the text. But the problem is, when I enter the exact same information as my Playwright tests, `await data.text()` returns an empty string. When I look in `data` the size of the blob is `0` while the size actually has a number when running from my Playwright tests.

Can someone explain me why it works with my Playwright tests?